# java date comparison help required

Tags: java, datetime

I am trying to compare two dates. Here is my date compare code...

```
Date dbLastModified = getBulletinBarMessageLastModified();
Date bulletinBarMessageLastModified = bulletinBarForm.getLastModified();

if (dbLastModified.after(bulletinBarMessageLastModified)){
    throw new ReportingManagerOptimisticLockingException(optimisticLockingMessage);
}

public Date getBulletinBarMessageLastModified() {
    Timestamp lastModifiedTimestamp = getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(BULLETIN_BAR_MSG_LAST_MODIFIED_SQL,Timestamp.class);
    Date lastModifiedDate = new Date(lastModifiedTimestamp.getTime());
    return lastModifiedDate;
}
```

...

```
dbLastModified  - Tue Apr 01 22:29:04 EST 2014
bulletinBarMessageLastModified  - Tue Apr 01 22:29:04 EST 2014
```

I am confused as to why even when some dates are seemingly equal (such as those two) why my code is throwing the `ReportingManagerOptimisticLockingException` exception, implying that one is *after* the other. Is my understanding of date comparisons wrong?

Comment: Dates are stored as milliseconds, so they're probably actually different in the milliseconds, even though they look the same.

Comment: Timestamps do not work reliably as a version data type. For one thing timestamp resolution on your client, the DB OS and the DB itself might differ. And even with a quite high resolution there will be those cases where two updates happen in the same moment and are not detected as different versions.

Comment: Yes. you guys were right. Thanks .....first date: 2014-04-02T08:35:12.000+1100
......second date: 2014-04-02T08:35:12.015+1100

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Timestamp.getTime()` considers the ***Nanoseconds*** as well.
So even the `toString()` returns a same output, actually there is a *nano* difference.

But `java.util.Date` only deals with ***Milliseconds***.

Comment: Notreally.  `after` deals with dates, so it only compares milliseconds.  It looks like there's a millisecond difference, but because OP is printing the dates to the nearest second, this won't show up.  The nanoseconds in a `TimeStamp` have nothing to do with this.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#after%28java.util.Date%29)

you can read the following:

> after
>
> public boolean after(Date when)
>
> ```
> Tests if this date is after the specified date.
>
> Parameters:
>     when - a date. 
> Returns:
>     true if and only if the instant represented by this Date object is strictly later than the instant represented by when; false
> ```
>
> otherwise. 
>       Throws:
>           NullPointerException - if when is null.

Now, it is either a `Java` bug or `dbLastModified` is really after `bulletinBarMessageLastModified` with a few nanoseconds.

If the following is `false`:

```
dbLastModified.after(dbLastModified)
```

then it is probably not a `Java` bug, but it so happens that the second date is after the first one with a few nanoseconds.